# I just moved 300GB+ files from one external drive to another, but now the folders show up empty?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I selected all the folders and used cut and paste. But the second external drive has 331GB data, only I can't see it. All the folders show up empty. I use Windows 10.
One of the folders and all its subfolders show 256 copies of a folder labelled ".fseventsd".

Comment: I had weird similar thing happen. The drive showed as being almost full but the files would not show. http://superuser.com/questions/948456/win-8-1-made-new-vhds-txts-copied-to-d-partition-of-another-machine-on-boot

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SuperUser!! I strongly recommend trying GetDataBack for NTFS or FAT... (hint: search on 4shared.com and it will benefit you ;D)

Comment: [.Trashes, .fseventsd, and .Spotlight-V100](http://blog.hostilefork.com/trashes-fseventsd-and-spotlight-v100/)

Answer (score 0):

Try scaning both of your externals. It's the only thing you can do now. If you find a virus there might be not chance of getting your files back, and if you do find a virus check all your files on the external and see if they have random sizes and names, if they do, your files are probably gone because the virus has overwriten them.